# Content area didn't scroll in xamarin side bar component

Tags: ios, xamarin

I'm currently using this component in xamarin 
http://components.xamarin.com/view/SidebarNavigation and basically it works fine, but when i try to use a UITableViewController as one of my content and add a lot of items in tableview that will basically make the app scroll, the app didn't actually scroll when you run it to iOS simulator, I haven't add any code yet to my contentController and I haven't change any property on my UITableView, just drag a UITableViewController from toolbox set up the code behind controller, storyboard ID, Restoration ID add some data to the tableView then hit run.

I don't know if this is a bug or I'm doing something wrong? any idea everyone? or you can just give me any free component that use as navigation drawer in iOS app.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a bug!

You can solve it by wrapping your uitableview in a uiview.
Just make a fresh view controller and put a tableview as its only child!

Good luck ;)